# How to output the value of an object of non default data type

Tags: python, object

Some default data types, such as int, list, tuple, string and so on, can directly output the value of the object. For example:

```py
a=10

a

Out[123]: 10
```

Other objects, such as enumeration objects, can only list their addresses.

```py
t=enumerate(some_ list)

t

Out[125]: <enumerate at 0x17be6e58600>
```

Is there any way to output the values of objects of the non default data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it works with `int` but not with `enumerate` is that enumerate is a generator (try the same with `range(10)`), thus it does not have a value (yet) - that is how generators work, they only give you a value, when you explicit ask for it.

If you want to get the items from `enumerate` you'll need to "access" them by iterate over `enumerate` e.g

```py
t = enumerate(["hello","world"])
ll = list(t) #Now we "execute" enumerate and get the values from it
ll
#[(0,"hello"),(1,"world")]
```

or you can loop over it

```py
for el in t:
   print(el)

#(0,"hello")
#(1,"world")
```

If you want to get one value at a time, you can use the method `__next__` i.e

```py
t = enumerate(["hello","world"])
t.__next__()
#(0,"hello")
t.__next__()
#(1,"world")
```

Note, when you have "called" a generator you need to initialize it again, before being able to get values from it e.g

```py
t = enumerate(["hello","world")
list(t)
#[(0,"hello"),(1,"world")]
list(t)  
#[]
```

as you can see, the next time we try to iterate over the generator, it is empty